# Getelementbyclassname return Error

Tags: vba

I've been using a code I've made for scraping some data from some sites, now that I tried to add a new site to the list I get this error: Object doesnt support this property or method.
Can I use the exact same code as others but this time I get this message, does anyone know why?
The error message appears when I try to get the elementbyclassname.

```
Sub Zelo()
    Dim dia As String
    Dim mes As String
    Dim ano As String

    dia = "14"
    mes = "09"
    ano = "13"

    Dim cont As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    URL = "http://www2.zelo.com.br/weddingListSearch.aspx?dsName=&dsLocation=&dtWedding=" & dia & "/" & mes & "/" & ano & "&idproduct=&qty="

    IE.Navigate(URL)

    Do
        DoEvents()
    Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4

    cont = 0

    With IE
        For Each ele In .document.getelementsbyclassname("name") ' Here I have the error message
            If ele.classname = "place" Then
                cont = cont + 1
            End If
        Next ele
    End With

    Sheets("Plan2").Range("A2") = cont

    IE.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: have you debug stepped through the code?

Comment: Yes, I ran line to line and this is the part I get an error, I tried Pradeep's sugestion, changed it to GetElementsByTagName, but I don't get any elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no method as `getelementsbyclassname` in Internet Explorer/WebBrowser control.

I am assuming you wanted to use `GetElementsByTagName` instead, which gets all the elements with specified tag name.

**EDIT :**

Updated code sample:

```
With IE
    For Each ele In .document.GetElementsByTagName("td")
        If ele.classname = "place" Then
            cont = cont + 1
        End If
    Next ele
End With
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not a VBA and I know nothing about creating websites, but I used this code to get infos from others two websites.
How would you count the number of times this tag (PLACE) appears in the source code?
    `<td class="place" style="width:10%; text-align:center;"><span>Aberta</span></td>`

Comment: Holy Diddly-Ho!
It worked perfectly! Your answer just gave me a reason to re-check all my codes and try to make it better and understandable!